# awk - delete line if next lines don't match pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I would like to solve the following issue and so far I think awk might be the right too, but proof me if I'm wrong.

I have a console output that follows this scheme:

```
HEADER: HeaderInfo1
Details 1
Details 2
HEADER: HeaderInfo2
HEADER: HeaderInfo3
Details 3
Details 4
HEADER: HeaderInfo4
```

I would like to transform this into the following:

```
HeaderInfo1: Details 1
HeaderInfo1: Details 2
HeaderInfo3: Details 3
HeaderInfo3: Details 4
```

So as you can see, each Detail belongs to the closest header. The number of Details per Header is variable
Empty Headers should be ignored.

I tried all sorts of regex and sed magic, but this seems like a case for awk I think. However I don't quite know where to start.

Comment: sorry, was a mistake. of course you are right. I corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your info is in a file called `info`:

```
$ awk '/^HEADER/{hdr=$2;next} {print hdr": "$0}' info
HeaderInfo1: Details 1
HeaderInfo1: Details 2
HeaderInfo3: Details 3
HeaderInfo3: Details 4
```

#### Explanation

The `awk` program divides into two pieces:

- `/^HEADER/{hdr=$2;next}`

  For lines that begin with `HEADER`, the second field is saved in the variable `hdr` and then `awk` is instructed to skip to the next line.
- `{print hdr": "$0}`

  For all other lines, the most recent value of header `hdr` is printed, followed a colon, followed by the line (`$0`).

Comment: this works so perfectly! Thank you such much! It's crazy how easy this task is with the right tools and if the force is strong with you. gotta learn more awk